# Book recommendations on Information Theory and Probability

Tags: probability-theory, book-recommendation, information-theory

I'm studying statistics and data analysis and I'm looking for some introductory texts about Information theory and how it is used in probability theory and statistics. I'd like to write my bachelor's thesis on the subject but I haven't been successful in finding plenty of material covering this area. All I have really found is "Information Theory and Statistics" from Kullback but other sources would be appreciated. Especially texts with some practical examples of the theory presented would be useful.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: _Elements of Information Theory_, by Thomas and Cover, is a good reference.

Comment: [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itila/) is very relevant to data science. The website contains materials from the free downloadable PDF file to lectures given by the author.

Comment: Thank you very much, both look really interesting